# Kafka Producer Timestamp not able to read in from consumer record

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 0.10.2 `KafkaProducer` to produce data in topic.
Below is my code.

```
    ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord(topic, (Integer)null, Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), partitionKey.getBytes(), message.getBytes());
Future<RecordMetadata> future = this.producer.send(record, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                if(e != null) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error producing to topic " + partitionKey, e.getCause());
                } else {
                    LOGGER.info(" Successfully produced topic " + recordMetadata.topic() + " on partition " + recordMetadata.partition() + "at " + recordMetadata.timestamp());
                }

            }
        });
```

this message is getting replicated through mirrormaker in different cluster. I wrote a Mirrormaker Handler to send capture the delay though per message.
when I check the timestamp at mirrormaker consumer. I am not able to see the timestamp. below is the code for mirrormaker handler.

```
 @Override
    public List<ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>> handle(BaseConsumerRecord record) {

LOGGER.debug("Timestamp from dal producer "+record.timestamp());
return Collections.singletonList(new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(topicToSend,partitionToSend,timeStampAtMM, record.key(), record.value()));
}
```

Comment: you mean the timestamp is null or -1?

Comment: I am getting -1 when I try to read timestamp from ```ConsumerRecord```

Comment: Could you add some print logic in the `onCompletion` to make sure timestamp is correctly generated on the producer side? This could be helpful to narrow down the root cause. Besides, did you use the old consumer or the new consumer for MirrorMaker?

Comment: I am using new Consumer. Also I have added the timestamp in producer code.

Comment: Did you set message.format.version in server.properties?

Comment: @amethystic I have log.message.format.version=0.8.2.1. Is this the property you are talking about?

Comment: yes, timestamp is introduced since 0.10.0.0. Old message format does not support timestamp.

Comment: @amethystic Thanks It helped.

Comment: @amethystic You should write that up as a quick answer, it helped me too.